# Are there any stotras that i can recite without following a vegetarian diet

Tags: scripture, vedas, food, manuscripts, meat

I have a health condition that keeps me from being a vegan. I have to consume animal protein almost everyday in moderation. But my consumption of meat etc interferes with my daily recitation of stotras. I dislike washing my hair every morning. I wish there were some stotras that I could recite without having to follow any vegan diet restrictions. I read aditya hrudayam, hanuman and durga stotras daily

Comment: Recite stotras in the morning before taking non veg

Comment: All stotras, I don't see diet being any problem here, but it is recommended to recite them before food.

Comment: reciting before taking food without having to wash my hair everyday is ok?

Comment: Without morning bath one is not pure .. so you have to bath daily before recital besides wearing clean clothes. @Santhosh

Comment: Yes usually I recite stotras after morning bath before having food. I wish to know if washing my hair (head bath) everyday is compulsory @rickross

Comment: Head bath is actually what constitutes a ritual bath .. if that is not possible for you to do on a daily basis then you can wash your feet, hands, face and rinse your mouth once ..that is kind of a substitute for bathing. @Santhosh